# How to remove the leftmost bit and add bit in its rightmost bit

Tags: c#, binary, hex, byte

How to remove the leftmost bit?

I have a hexadecimal value `BF`

Its binary representation is `1011 1111`

How can I remove the first bit, which is `1`, and then it will become `0111 1110`?

How to add "0" also to its last part?

Comment: What code have you tried writing to do this? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: I want to try it in C#, i don't know how to code it.. I think i should need to use ">>" but I don't know how that operator functioning..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int i=0xbf;
int j=(i<<1) & 0xff;
```

Comment: "<<" this operator, is this removing the "1" in it's leftmost bit?
and what is the purpose of 0xff?

Comment: The << operator will shift the argument right, filling up with zeroes, so binary `0000 0000 1011 1111` will become `0000 0001 0111 1110`. Since you want to cut off after 8 bits, I do a bitwise logical AND (Operator &) with `0000 0000 1111 1111`, which results in `0000 0000 0111 1110`- your desired result

Comment: Is it required to used Operator &? since I already get my desired result in "<<" operator?

Comment: After the << operator, you get `0000 0001 0111 1110`, which is 0x017E, but you want 0x7E, so you need to cut off. You might get around this with the `byte` datatype: byte j=(byte)(i<<1) - this does exatcly the same thing internally

Comment: thanks Eugen Rieck.. nice explanation about this "<<" operator.

Answer (score 8):

### To set bit N of variable `x` to `0`

```
x &= ~(1 << N);
```

**How it works:** The expression 1 << N is one bit [shifted N times to the left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w). For N = 7, this would be

```
1000 0000
```

The [bitwise NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) [operator `~`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) inverts this to

```
0111 1111
```

Then the result is [bitwise ANDed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with `x`, giving:

```
xxxx xxxx
0111 1111
--------- [AND]
0xxx xxxx
```

Result: bit 7 (zero-based count starting from the LSB) is turned off, all others retain their previous values.

### To set bit N of variable `x` to `1`

```
x |= 1 << N;
```

How it works: this time we take the shifted bit and [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) it with `x`, giving:

```
xxxx xxxx
1000 0000
--------- [OR]
1xxx xxxx
```

Result: Bit 7 is turned on, all others retain their previous values.

### Finding highest order bit set to `1`:

If you don't know which is the highest bit set to 1 you can find out on the fly. There are many ways of doing this; a reasonable approach is

```
int x = 0xbf;
int highestSetBit = -1; // assume that to begin with, x is all zeroes
while (x != 0) {
    ++highestSetBit;
    x >>= 1;
}
```

At the end of the loop, `highestSetBit` will be 7 as expected.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/AAbGY)**.

Answer (score 1):

or you could do:
 (i*2) && 0xff
 if you'd rather not do bit twiddling. >>1 is the equivalent of /2, and <<1 is the equivalent of *2.

Comment: what is the purpose of  0xff?